# Get unique values for two different columns for certain dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains some user data:

```
user_id | guest_id | time_seen | action_performed | longitude | latitude
-------------------------------------------------------------------------  
 123     | NULL     | Jan 10    | search           | -127      | 35  
 152     | NULL     | Dec 10    | login            | -128      | 34   
 172     | NULL     | Dec 15    | search           | -125      | 35   
 123     | NULL     | Jan 10    | login            | -127      | 35   
 NULL    | GUEST1   | Jan 10    | search           | -127      | 35   
 NULL    | GUEST1   | Dec 10    | search           | -127      | 35   
 NULL    | GUEST2   | Jan 10    | browse           | -127      | 35   
 NULL    | GUEST3   | Dec 10    | browse           | -127      | 35
```

I need to get a list of the unique user ids and guest ids for a given time span. The same row never has a valid user ID AND a valid guest ID at the same time. The query I'm using currently is:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM stats 
    WHERE time_seen >= "2011-12-1 00:00:00" 
      AND time_seen < "2012-1-1 00:00:00" 
    GROUP BY guest_id 
UNION 
SELECT * 
    FROM stats 
    WHERE time_seen >= "2011-12-1 00:00:00" 
      AND time_seen < "2012-1-1 00:00:00" 
    GROUP BY user_id;
```

So I'd expect to retrieve:

```
user_id | guest_id | time_seen | action_performed | longitude | latitude
-------------------------------------------------------------------------  
 152     | NULL     | Dec 10    | login            | -128      | 34   
 172     | NULL     | Dec 15    | search           | -125      | 35 
 NULL    | GUEST1   | Dec 10    | search           | -127      | 35
 NULL    | GUEST3   | Dec 10    | browse           | -127      | 35
```

The real table contains about 11 million entries as of this time and is growing every day, so obviously I'm interested in making the query as efficient as possible. This query seems a little suboptimal (unless there's internal optimization) since I perform the same query each time, just group it by different things afterwards.

Is there any way to improve my query, or is this the best I can do?

In response to questions below:

The dates do have a timestamp value, I just wanted to simplify for the purposes of the post.

There is no overlap between user_id values and guest_id values.

Comment: do the dates also have timestamp value ie hh:mm:ss..?

Comment: Is there overlap betweeen user_id values and guest_id values?

Comment: Have you looked at doing a Join along with a Select using not in.. what about if the user_id is null.. can you Alias that column and assing a Value + n for example..

Comment: I don't think your current query produces the output you're expecting.

Comment: The dates do have a timestamp value, I just wanted to simplify for the purposes of the post.



There is no overlap between user_id values and guest_id values.



@JoeStefanelli: I'm relatively sure it does, at least it did on the test data that I used. Where do you think I'm going wrong?

Updating question with responses to comments as well.

Comment: @Catherine Your use of GROUP BY is allowing the engine to arbitrarily choose which values are returned for the other, non-aggregated columns. I'd prefer/expect to see an explicit choice made for columns such as `time_seen`. For example, perhaps you'd want the most recent value returned.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli Yes, I recognize that, however for what I'm trying to do (simply get a list of all users active in the system in the last month), it doesn't matter much. The place where it may matter is the lat/lon assigned to the user, as I'm putting them in "city" buckets, but since I'm trying to just get a rough idea of users active overall, I don't need the granularity of being certain of recording the user in every different city s/he may have logged in from. BTW, thanks for editing my question for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no overlap between the `user_id` values and the `guest_id` values then you could `GROUP BY` the `COALESCE` of those two columns and not use the `UNION`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion:

```
SELECT `user_id`, `guest_id`, `time_seen`, `action_performed`, `longitude`, `latitude`
FROM stats
WHERE guest_id IS NOT NULL AND time_seen BETWEEN  "2011-12-1 00:00:00" AND "2012-1-1 00:00:00"
GROUP BY guest_id

UNION

SELECT `user_id`, `guest_id`, `time_seen`, `action_performed`, `longitude`, `latitude`
FROM stats
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL AND time_seen BETWEEN  "2011-12-1 00:00:00" AND "2012-1-1 00:00:00"
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Things changed:

1) explicitly list which fields you want returned

2) Used BETWEEN rather than 2 comparisons

3) Added `guest_id IS NOT NULL` and `user_id IS NOT NULL` to the WHERE clauses.  That way you don't end up grouping all the guests together when looking at the users and vice-versa.

Comment: I think the earlier `COALESCE` suggestion makes the most sense, but I'll definitely use some of your other suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a list of vistors, then:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(user_id, guest_id), longitude, latitude
FROM stats
WHERE time_seen >= "2011-12-1 00:00:00" AND time_seen < "2012-1-1 00:00:00";
```

Comment: I need to know the visitor locations as well.

Comment: I edited it but if a user logged in from 2 different places within your time frame then you will get that 2 records for the same user.

Comment: Right, that's no good for me. I think the GROUP BY COALESCE suggestion is the best for my case.